# Mixed Effect Model with clustered observations and longitudinal data with lme4

Tags: time-series, clustering, mixed-model, modeling

I am having trouble trying to conceptualize how to set up a mixed-effect model with data that is both clustered and measured over time.

In particular, I have a data set of test scores (DV) from various schools over a four year period (2011 - 2014). The schools are clustered within districts.

In 2013, the test was changed and so I'm using z-scores to compare the tests to account for the different metric.

I also have the percentage of several ethnicities and genders in each school.

What I'm struggling to understand is how to set up a MLM that takes into account both the repeated measures and clustering. I'm using R and lme4.

I have several research questions.

1. How are the different districts performing? Did the change make test performance more even? (Is one district doing much better than the others, did changing the test result in the districts performing closer together?)
2. How does the percentage of different ethnicities/gender affect test scores? Do schools with more of a certain ethnicity perform better/worse? Is the new test "fairer" such that ethnicity plays a smaller role in test score?
3. How are the schools/districts doing over time? Is performance going up, down, or staying about the same?

Here is a toy dataset:

```
School <- rep(sprintf("School%02d", 1:50), each = 4)

Year <- rep(c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2014), times = 50)

District <- rep(c("d1","d2","d3","d4","d5"), each = 40)

set.seed(1)

PercAsian <- runif(50)

PercAsian <- rep(PercAsian, each = 4)

zScores <- c(-1.140711906,-1.134009107,-1.334997943,-2.005383099,0.218759194,0.504363,0.265284195,-0.445461834,0.154022475,-0.795035567,-0.481514136,-0.395141794,-0.622818154,0.052398281,0.425312408,0.108058614,0.218759194,-0.343070848,-0.001429495,-1.200262446,-0.493344716,-0.569053208,-0.481514136,-0.697062038,0.736652946,0.22188505,1.332138953,1.013819349,-0.299134558,-0.512557618,-0.161457709,-0.244181671,-0.687554873,-1.190504697,-1.121626992,-1.804102936,-1.593868939,-1.416487056,-2.028453537,-1.250582487,-0.752291592,-0.625548798,-0.90825604,-0.193861631,3.002438112,2.707691005,2.292308236,1.667979879,-0.817028311,-0.908026747,-2.081796274,-1.502182691,-0.16966112,1.973248337,0.852054312,1.617659838,-0.234397839,-0.625548798,-0.321485923,0.611259022,0.154022475,-0.004097309,0.425312408,0.007418533,0.348232632,0.22188505,-0.214800447,0.812539185,2.678754517,3.046664544,2.719050139,2.925980899,0.671916227,0.956327719,0.585340622,0.661579063,1.384020136,1.238805668,1.278796215,0.963499308,0.154022475,0.39137182,1.225453477,0.913179267,2.225597484,2.029743927,2.078937284,2.070540205,1.642967012,1.182310078,1.598852643,0.711899104,0.348232632,0.108893871,-0.214800447,0.158378655,1.966650608,1.069318899,1.91890907,1.71829992,1.578230293,1.351796848,1.652195381,1.667979879,1.83717717,1.916752747,3.145792043,2.422780491,0.801389665,0.108893871,0.531997884,0.208698696,1.642967012,1.125814488,2.238965498,1.617659838,3.002438112,2.425213056,3.412505733,2.473100532,1.513493574,1.634274797,1.865566333,1.71829992,-1.270185344,-0.625548798,-0.214800447,0.057738573,1.513493574,1.408292438,1.492167167,1.617659838,1.901913889,1.803761567,1.758880857,1.869260042,0.154022475,0.33487623,0.90539705,0.913179267,2.031387327,1.916752747,1.652195381,1.76861996,1.189809979,0.33487623,1.598852643,1.315739593,1.966650608,1.916752747,1.865566333,1.667979879,1.254546698,1.295301258,1.91890907,1.567339797,0.607179508,0.44786741,-0.054772233,-0.193861631,1.319283417,1.464788028,1.865566333,1.315739593,0.801389665,0.61735418,0.37196967,0.057738573,-0.428607997,0.27838064,0.63868336,0.007418533,1.578230293,1.747265977,1.172110739,1.164779471,0.913179267,1.578230293,1.916752747,1.972251808,1.76861996,0.671916227,-1.247000287,0.607179508,1.182310078,1.332138953,1.667979879,2.096124046,2.029743927,2.345650974,1.667979879,-0.299134558,0.108893871,0.105255981,0.510618941,-0.687554873,-0.964522337,-0.321485923,-0.948662242, -1.075975187)
Dat <- data.frame(School, Year, District, PercAsian, zScores)
```

This is my current model:

```
lm1 <- lmer(zScores ~ PercAsian * Year + (1|District:School) + (1|School)
```

Comment: Wow cowboy! Too many unknowns! :D How are the $z$-scores calculated? Is there an explicit mapping between the 2011-2013 and 2014 test? What does that test measure? (To question this a bit further the new test might destroyed the non-Asian kids scores trying to account for ethnicity but did not do anything for the Asian kids so it is not *fairer* just *bad in different ways*?) The $z$-scores will have by definition variance one how do you judge *the districts performing closer together*? (+1 fun question!)

Comment: 1. The z-scores were calculated using the grand mean and SD for each year, and using the z-score formula for each school.

Comment: 2. In 2013, a new curriculum was implemented that changed what students, are expected to know, but I believe the scores are still comparable.  
  
3. The tests all measure "Math" performance for 5th grade students.